# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javax/servlet/ServletException : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, web

I am using myEclipse 10 with Java EE 6.0 on JDK 1.6 to develop a web app based on Spring framework 4.1.7. During the unit test stage, following testing error reported:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javax/servlet/ServletException : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(MockMvcBuilders.java:71)
    at spittr.web.HomeControllerTest.shouldShowRecentSpittles(HomeControllerTest.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

The source code raising the error is the code line of "standaloneSetup(controller)" in the following:

```
    @Test
    public void shouldShowRecentSpittles() throws Exception{
        List<Spittle> expectedSpittles = createSpittleList(20);
        SpittleRepository mockRepository = mock(SpittleRepository.class);
        when(mockRepository.findSpittles(Long.MAX_VALUE, 20)).thenReturn(expectedSpittles);
        SpittleController controller = new SpittleController(mockRepository);
        MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller).setSingleView(
                new InternalResourceView("/WEB-INF/views/spittles.jsp")).build();

        mockMvc.perform(get("/spittles"))
            .andExpect(view().name("spittles"))
            .andExpect(model().attributeExists("spittleList"))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("spittleList", expectedSpittles));

    }
```

What is the problem? How to correct it?

Comment: The problem is very obvious: one part of your application comes with bytecode compiled for Java 7 (probably spring); but your JVM only supports Java 6 bytecode. So, next time: do some prior research please!

Comment: Spring 4 requires only Java 6, should be something else. Since you're probably not actually writing a [JEE6 app with spring side by side](http://de.slideshare.net/reza_rahman/java-ee-and-spring-sidebyside-34320697) but rather a spring app, and spring 4 works fine with java 8, I'd update to that. Or 7, but even that is EOL since early 2015.